# How can I get the snippet info from my api json response?

Tags: c#, json

This is what my logic looks like:

```
public void SetVideoInfo(string videoID)
{
    var url = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos? 
        part=snippet&fields=items(snippet(title,description))&id=" + videoID + 
        "&key=somekey");
    url.Timeout = -1;

    var urlRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    var urlResponse = url.Execute(urlRequest);
    var response = JObject.Parse(urlResponse.Content);
    var data = (JArray)response["items"];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        var videoTitle = data[i]["title"];
        var videoDescription = data[i]["description"];

        this.VideoTitle = videoTitle.ToString().Trim();
        this.VideoDescription = videoDescription.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

This is what the API response looks like:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "some title",
                "description": "some description"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My current logic gets up to "snippet" but I get nulls for title and description. I just want to know how am I able to get to the title and description attributes.

Comment: RestSharp has methods for parsing results directly into proper C# classes, use them instead of messing around with `JObject`s and `JArray`s.

Comment: Also, that is not a full JSON response - did you miss the surrounding `{.....}`?

Comment: I left out some curly braces. This is what the response really looks like.                         {
    "items": [
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "some title",
                "description": "some description"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestSharp has methods for parsing results directly into proper C# classes, use them instead of messing around with `JObject`s and `JArray`s. Off the top of my head, something like this should work.

First, make some classes to hold your data:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Snippet Snippet { get; set; }
}

public class Snippet
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now call the generic method of RestSharp:

```
var urlResponse = url.Execute<Root>(urlRequest);
```

Now you can access the properties in a type-safe way.

```
var title = urlResponse.Items[0].Snippet.Title
var description = urlResponse.Items[0].Snippet.Description
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I'll try it out see if I can get it working. I am getting an error at Items where it's Items[0] but I think i'm just missing something.

Comment: @seacode you are getting error at Items[0], may be there is no value at index 0 in Items. Check once

Comment: @Rajesh Well, it's not like out of range exception error or anything like that. Its underlined red saying that iRestResponse<Root> does not contain a definition for Items.

Comment: Oh, you may need something like `urlResponse.Content.Items...`

Comment: .Content doesn't work but .Data does. So that's a step in the right direction. However, they still come back as null, so maybe my indexing is wrong maybe?

Comment: .Data actually seems to work. I'm not sure what I did because it didn't seem to work earlier when I tried it but its all good now and it's mainly because of you guys so thanks, I really appreciate it!